# Count maximum consecutive occurences of a string in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe in which I would like to count the number of consecutive occurences of a specific string in one column.

Let's say I have the following dataframe.

```
   col1
0  string1
1  string1
2  string1
3  string2
4  string3
5  string3
6  string1
```

I would like to define `a` as the number of maximum consecutive occurences of for example `string1` or any other string in `col1`.

In this case, `a`should return `3` if I want to search for `string1` and return `2` for `string3`.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do the usual trick of grouping consecutive values:

```
df1 = df.groupby((df.col1 != df.col1.shift()).cumsum().rename(None)).col1.agg(['size', 'first'])
#   size    first
#1     3  string1
#2     1  string2
#3     2  string3
#4     1  string1
```

Then `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates` to find the largest:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('size').drop_duplicates('first', keep='last').set_index('first').rename_axis(None)
#         size
#string2     1
#string3     2
#string1     3
```

So now you can look them up easily:

```
df1.loc['string1']
#size    3
#Name: string1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.col1.groupby(df.col1.ne(df.col1.shift()).cumsum()).size().max()`

Comment: @piRSquared just want to say hi to you sir :-)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just `itertools` `groupby`, the order here keep the same as original df

```
import itertools 
pd.DataFrame([x,len(list(y))] for x , y in itertools.groupby(df['col1']))
Out[92]: 
         0  1
0  string1  3
1  string2  1
2  string3  2
3  string1  1
```

---

```
pd.DataFrame([x,len(list(y))] for x , y in itertools.groupby(df['col1'])).groupby(0)[1].max()
Out[94]: 
0
string1    3
string2    1
string3    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi  _ _ _ _ _ o/

Comment: @piRSquared Nice to see you back :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is still returning consecutive occurences for all the strings when I only need the maximum number. I understand that from your answer I can do the same ``sort_values`` + ``drop_duplicates`` as in the post I chose as best answer to achieve the same result.

Comment: @SdJunk groupby+max

Comment: Thank you for the update. It works for what I intend it to now