# Count maximum occurences in a dataframe column for a specific timespan

Tags: python, pandas

This question is intended as a follow-up to the following question: [Count maximum consecutive occurences of a string in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595188/count-maximum-consecutive-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-dataframe-column)

Let's say I now have the following dataframe:

```
      col1      col2
0  21.02.2020  string1
1  19.02.2020  string1
2  16.02.2020  string1
3  14.02.2020  string2
4  10.02.2020  string3
5  08.02.2020  string3
6  02.02.2020  string1
```

How can I now determine the maximum number of occurences of a string in any period of one week starting on a Monday and ending on a Sunday? And how can I do the same for any period of two weeks starting on a Monday and ending on the next Sunday?

I would like to count the occurences so that if the dataframe spans 5 weeks, it would return the highest number of occurences of `string1` in a week in that timespan. And if the dataframe were for example only:

```
      col1      col2
0  21.02.2020  string1
```

it would return `1` for `string1`.

Comment: How looks ouput DataFrame from first sample data? Is it [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need for test number of rows span in weeks from Monday to Sunday:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], dayfirst=True)
g = df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()).cumsum()

df1 = df.groupby([g, pd.Grouper(freq='W-Mon', key='col1')])['col2'].agg(['first','size'])
print (df1)
                   first  size
col2 col1                     
1    2020-02-17  string1     1
     2020-02-24  string1     2
2    2020-02-17  string2     1
3    2020-02-10  string3     2
4    2020-02-03  string1     1

df2 = (df1.sort_values('size')
          .drop_duplicates('first', keep='last')
          .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df2)
              first  size
col1                     
2020-02-17  string2     1
2020-02-24  string1     2
2020-02-10  string3     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that this answer works for one week, right? So I assume that if I want to do the same for 2 weeks then I should use freq='2W-Mon'. Is that right?